# Embedded Rust- How to prevent generation of 'extra' code for ISR

Tags: rust, embedded

I'm trying to write simple RTOS and I'm struggling with extra asm code generated by compiler. Code targets cortex-m4 cpu for which I'm using cortex-m and cortex-m-rt crates.
I was able to remove trampoline by using **#[no_mangle]** attribute but I can't figure out how to remove/prevent generation of `push {r7, lr}` and `pop     {r7, pc}`  instructions.

Here is my PendSV code:

```
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[no_mangle]
pub fn PendSV() {
    unsafe{
        asm!("nop")
    }
}
```

Here is generated code:

```
push    {r7, lr}
mov     r7, sp
nop                                                                                                                                      
pop     {r7, pc}
```

I'm looking for some sort of attribute or compiler option so I could have just `nop` generated as part of PendSV function. Is it possible?

Comment: I think it might be in the pipeline: https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/1201-naked-fns.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `PendSV` a [naked function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1201). "Naked" means that no prelude and no return code is generated for this function.

So, naively, something like this:

```rust
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(naked_functions)]

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[no_mangle]
#[naked]
pub fn PendSV() {
    unsafe {
        asm!("nop")
    }
}
```

With the following code you get two warnings:

> warning: Rust ABI is unsupported in naked functions
>
> warning: asm in naked functions must use `noreturn` option

To remedy, use the C ABI and the `noreturn` option:

```rust
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[no_mangle]
#[naked]
pub extern "C" fn PendSV() {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "nop",
            options(noreturn)
        )
    }
}
```

Under x86, this compiles to (via [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fdWPqW1P4)):

```
PendSV:
        nop
        ud2
```

The [ud2](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html) is likely still not what you want. It is generated because by now, you have indicated that the function does not return, yet, after executing a single `nop`, the execution flow will reach the end of the function (where it *would* return, if it weren't for the fact that you're using a naked function...)

So, it is your responsibility to decide what gets executed after `PendSV`. You likely want something like an infinite loop, a jump, or a "return from interrupt" instruction (`iret` speaking in x86 terms, I am not too familiar with ARM).

Comment: I it is no-return because as a naked function, the compiler does not know how to return.  you will therefore be responsible for returning yourself using the correct calling conventions and a the bl instruction on arm